# link_to jquery function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to coding in general, learning to code in rails, and feel like I'm missing something very fundamental with jquery.

On my user profile page, there's a link for users to change their avatar picture:

```
<div id="show_avatars_choice">
  <%= link_to "Change Avatar", "#", remote: true %>
</div>
```

Then, in /assets/javascripts/users.js, I have:

```
$("#show_avatars_choice").on("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("you clicked me");
})
```

Ultimately the alert will be replaced with some code that allows a selection of alternative avatar pictures to be displayed, but at this stage even the simple alert doesn't pop up when I click on the link.  What am I doing wrong?

The application.js file does contain the following lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.isDefaultPrevented/
Try this
`alert("you clicked me");
event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Thanks, but changing around those 2 lines didn't help either.

Comment: Do you have anything else besides those lines in users.js?

Comment: Yes - have another little stub function:
`$(".avatar_choice").on("click", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 alert("let's change your avatar!");
});`
But removing it didn't chage anything.

Comment: Using Developer tools (chrome/Safari) or Firebug (firefox), can you see jQuery and your JS file loaded ? Do you see any error in the JS console during load, or when you click ?

Comment: I think this must be my main problem - jQuery is loaded, as is all the .js.coffee files sitting in my /assets/javascripts/ folder.  But my all-important users.js isn't in the list of scripts shown by Firebug.  Time to learn a bit more about the assets pipeline...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Tracy Fu said was correct, the element should be on the page before the bind. Her answer is correct, but it's shorter if you do:

```
$(document).on("click", "#show_avatars_choice", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("you clicked me");
})​
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/sXVzU/

Also did some changes to Tracy Fu's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qRjt/

Comment: Agree with @Vincent. This is cleaner and more concise :)

Comment: Thanks Vincent and Tracy, especially for the elegant fiddles.  It still doesn't work however, looks like I'll have to learn how to use firebug properly so I can track it down.

Comment: Okay I'm an idiot.  So when I changed the automatically generated  users.js.coffee file to just users.js, I left the three commented lines '#Place all the behaviours and hooks...' in there, and so presumably that wasn't recognised as a comment in js, so users.js wasn't loaded.  Got rid of them, using Vincent's code above, and it all works a treat now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the issue is that you're binding the event before the element exists in the DOM? From what I understand, jQuery's `on` still requires that the element be on the page before the initial bind.

Could you try this:

```
// This will run when the DOM is loaded
$(function() {
  $("#show_avatars_choice").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("you clicked me");
  })
});
```

Here's a fiddle that shows trying to bind before and after the DOM load:
http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/FX5aC/